# Inductive step for mathematical induction

Tags: logic, induction

For the inductive step in mathematical induction, which of the following is correct?

“$P_k$ is true” $\implies$ “$P_{k+1}$ is true”

or

“$P_k\implies P_{k+1}$” is true

Is there a difference in the two statements above?

Comment: Is there a difference between "My cat is gray" and "'My cat is gray' is true"?

Comment: Presentation wise I guess there is still a difference because I thought in mathematical induction we are actually proving that the statement “$P_k \implies P_{k+1}$” is true...sorry I am just being particular in the presentation haha

Comment: They're all the same $P_k$ is a statement.  If we clain "Hey!  $P_k$!" we are declaring it to be true.  But saying: "$P_k$" or "$P_k$ is true" are both the same thing.  If $P_k$ is true then ... $P_k$  And if $P_k$ isn't to then... not $P_k$.... So "$P_k$ is true $\implies$ "$P_{k+1}$ is true".  Is the exact same thing as $P_k \implies P_{k+1}$ which is exactly the same as "$P_k \implies P_{k+1}$ is true".

Comment: I agree with “$P_k \implies P_{k+1}$” and “$P_k$ is true $\implies P_{k+1}$ is true“ are the same. But still it is an argument which can be true or false as a whole. So to say “$P_k \implies P_{k+1}$” is actually true has a different implication. Am I right? Haha so confusing...

Comment: "to to say “Pk⟹Pk+1” is actually true has a different implication" Not by strict logic it doesn't.  $P_k \to P_{k+1}$ can be true if $P_k$ is false.  But then "$P_k \to P_{k+1}$ is true" can be true if $P_k$ is false or "$P_k$ is true" is false.  "Haha so confusing..."  I *honestly* do not think it is.  "Is it true your cat is gray", "Yes".  "So your cat is gray" "I just said so".   If $x$ and "$x$ is true" mean the *exact* same thing in *every* circumstance, there isn't *any* confusion at all. (Unless you are Lewis Caroll or a cartoon writer)..

Comment: I am sorry if you feel offended by my queries. I just want to clarify and learn. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You want to prove $P_k \implies P_{k+1}$. To do that, first assume $P_k$, then prove $P_{k+1}$, and you are done. Strictly speaking, phrases like "is true" are redundant.  Alternatively, you could assume both $P_k$ and $\neg P_{k+1}$, obtain a contradiction and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Note that the implication does not state the antecedent is in fact true, nor does it state the consequent is in fact true. It is simply saying that IF the antecedent were true, THEN the consequent would also be true.

This makes sense when you consider how a proof by induction is performed. The inductive step begins with assuming that $P(k)$ is true. You then attempt to validly deduce $P(k+1)$. If you can, then you are justified in stating $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$, meaning "if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true," or in other words, the $P(k+1)$ is true under the assumption that $P(k)$ is true. It is only when the antecedent is in fact true that the truthfulness of consequent is implied, which is why a proof by induction includes a basis step. The basis step provides the first instance for which the antecedent is true, which implies that your propositional function is true for the very next element. That, in turn, becomes the basis for implying the truthfulness of the propositional function for the next element after that, and so on, and so on...

Comment: I think I wasn’t clear in my question. Kindly see my updated question. Any difference now? Or still no difference?

Comment: So if I am to conclude my proof, which of the following conclusion is correct?

Comment: Still no difference. When you derive the statement $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$, you are proving the statement as a whole is true. In other words, you are showing that "$P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$" is true. With that being said, the statement itself means IF "$P(k)$ is true" THEN "$P(k+1)$ is true." Again, this does not mean that $P(k)$ is in fact true; it simply says the $P(k+1)$ is true under the assumption that $P(k)$ is true. It is only when $P(k)$ is true that $P(k+1)$ is true. This is why proof by induction includes the basis step - without it there is nothing that implies the consequent.

Comment: First version “Since P(0) is true and P(k) is true $\implies$ P(k+1) is true, so P(n) is true for all n”. Second version “Since P(0) is true and “P(k) $\implies$ P(k+1)” is true, so P(n) is true for all n”. So both are fine, is that right?

Comment: Yes, technically both are fine, but I would go with the second one because it is less verbose. The meaning of the statement is understood and doesn't need to spelled out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for showing your gratitude!

Comment: @LanaDR - if you don't mind, please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!